# How to use xargs to get elapsed time for running processes

Tags: linux, command-line, xargs

I want get the run times of some processes. Here is what I am doing

```
ps -ef | grep "python3 myTask.py" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 ps -p {} -o etime
```

I want to get the pids by

```
ps -ef | grep "python3 myTask.py" | awk '{print $2}'
```

then pass these along to the

```
ps -p {} -o etime
```

by using xargs, but its not working. I get

```
error: process ID list syntax error

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
error: process ID list syntax error

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you add the column for your first `ps` call, then grep/awk your process (can be combined to a single `awk` invocation)?

Comment: But nevertheless, you have to specify `-I{}`; otherwise you cannot use the placeholder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
pgrep -f "python3 myTask.py" | xargs -i{} ps -p {} -o etime
```

---

`pgrep` - Look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes.

`-f, --full` -
The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the  full  command  line  is
used.

For further reading, see `man pgrep`.

---

The missing part from the `xargs` segment was `-i{}`, which invokes the command for each argument, whilst {} will be replaced by it.

`-i[replace-str], --replace[=replace-str]` -
This  option  is  a  synonym  for -Ireplace-str if replace-str is specified.

For further reading, see `man xargs`.

Answer (score -1):

You must provide `-I{}` to xargs to set the placeholder; otherwise it cannot be used.

Nevertheless, your command is too complicated and involves too many intermediate steps (and a race-condition). Simply get your processes including elapsed time and filter the lines you need:

```
ps -eo etime,cmd | awk '/python3 myTask.py/{print $1}'
```

(no `xargs` anymore)